# Form authentication and AllowAnonymous in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net

I'm using form authentication in my asp.net mvc web application, and I want to redirect users to an appropriate page depending on the device (phone, pad or desktop), the problem is that the redirection works but the user must login. I want to redirect before login.
I used the AllowAnonymous filter on the Home controller (the controller that have this responsibility to redirect) but it seems not working.

my web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Login" defaultUrl="/" timeout="40320"/> <!-- monthly -->
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

**UPDATE:**Curiously [AllowAnonymous] works in another controllers, but not with the default HomeController !!!

Thank you.

Comment: are you saying that you want device specific Login pages?

Comment: I develop a web mobile app for an existing system and if the user uses a desktop device or a pad, the app must redirect to the standard site.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add [Authorize] attribute to your controller and [AllowAnonymous] to your action. Debug to whole process and make sure that application does not throw any exception.

This will help you

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add [Authorize] attribute to your view method

This will help you

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398049%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I put [Authorize] on protected actions. But in my case I want to allow anonymous access to my controller.

Answer (score 1):

In order to allow user to view particular pages without logging in you need to add a 'location' element specially authorizing particular pages or areas of your app.

If you have a page called '/landingpage/android', then add this to your web.config, right after the close tag for 'system.web'

```
<location path="landingpage/android">
   <system.web>
       <authorization>
           <allow users="*" />
       </authorization>
   </system.web>
</location>
```

You can add multiple location elements to your web.config file.

Answer (score 1):

For you to force everyuser to login you should have a BaseController which is derived in all other controllers and mark [Authorize] on the class level or you can mark actions or controllers with the [Authorize] attribute. Only on the login page keep the attribute [AllowAnonymous] so that all can reach the log in page

Comment: All my protected actions are decorated with [Authorize].

Comment: Can you share at what level you have the [AllowAnonymous] attribute, if  you have it at the class it may not work, if possible can you share the class

Comment: public class HomeController : Controller
        {
        //
        // GET: /Home/
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ...
        }

    }

Comment: can you try <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Login" defaultUrl="/" timeout="40320"/> <!-- monthly -->
</authentication> and remove the authorization tag. IMembership provider should ideally take care of it

Comment: If I remove the authorization tag, the redirection works, but the login doesn't, because I have a 401 error and ASP.NET doesn't redirect to login page with this error.

Comment: OK... now that redirection is working in correct the loginUL="~/ControllerName(in which login action is)/ActionName(logon)" and remove defaultUrl, just noticed it may be wrong

Comment: the defaultUrl is for the mobile app, if the redirection works, the user goto another site (the standard web application).